# Comparing user inputs to sqlite

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sqlite

I'm very new to Android programming (with some prior experience with php-mysql combo). Through some online tutorials, I've set up an sqlite adapter for interface with my mainactivity class for learning purpose.

I would appreciate if someone could explain if I could go about getting each user input/entry (e.g. entry, date) and use it to access and update the data in the sqlite database from the mainactivity class itself.

For example, given a certain name, age or location (any one) selected by the user, how do I use this information to search the database from the mainactivity (or whichever activity that hosts the exchange)?

```
    >>   MainActivity.......
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

DBAdapter myDb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
    myDb.open();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();  
    myDb.close();
}


private void displayText(String message) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDisplay);
    textView.setText(message);
}

public void onClick_AddRecord(View v) {
    displayText("Record added.");   
    long newId = myDb.insertRow("Kenneth", 17, "Indiana");

    Cursor cursor = myDb.getRow(newId);
    displayRecordSet(cursor);
}

public void onClick_ClearAll(View v) {
    displayText("Clicked clear all!");
    myDb.deleteAll();
}

public void onClick_DisplayRecords(View v) {
    displayText("Clicked display record!");

    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();
    displayRecordSet(cursor);
}


private void displayRecordSet(Cursor cursor) {
    String message = "";

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            int id = cursor.getInt(DBAdapter.COL_ROWID);
            String name = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_NAME);
            int ageber = cursor.getInt(DBAdapter.COL_AGE);
            String location = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_LOCATION);


            message += "id=" + id
                       +", name=" + name
                       +", age =" + age
                       +", location =" + location
                       +"\n";
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();

    displayText(message);
}
  }
```

---

```
    >>> DBAdapter.....
    public class DBAdapter {

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;

public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_AGE = "age";
public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";

public static final int COL_NAME = 1;
public static final int COL_AGE = 2;
public static final int COL_LOCATION = 3;


public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE, 

    KEY_LOCATION};

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDb";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Table";

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 23;  

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE 
        + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
        + KEY_AGE + " integer not null, "
        + KEY_LOCATION + " string null"
        + ");";


private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;


public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

public DBAdapter open() {
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    myDBHelper.close();
}

public long insertRow(String name, int age, String location) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_AGE, age);
    initialValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, location);

    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
}

public void deleteAll() {
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));              
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}

public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                        where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String name, int age, String location) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;

    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    newValues.put(KEY_AGE, age);
    newValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, location);

    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}


private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);           
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {     
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        onCreate(_db);
    }
}
}
```

I'm sorry if this question is too simple for some, but I am very keen to learn.

Comment: you all ready know about the sql operations, so it is easy for yo too. write the function in your DBAdapter class what you want to perform, and call like myDb.deleteAll(); where you want

Comment: Thanks for your confidence in me. But if you notice, for a specific query for a specific entry (e.g. name = Kenneth) in MainActivity, how do I pass that specific value 'Kenneth' back to the DBAdapter for processing (e.g. deleterow())?

Comment: for that you want to write another function bez the existing one is using rowId only. else pass two arguments with this one

Comment: I agree. The current one I have inhereted from a tutorial site only records the entry identity via 'rowID' which is created when the data is inserted. I'm looking for a way to link to/update a specific entry long after it has been created from MainActivity.

Comment: please do search in google, you will get what you are looking for

Comment: I did and couldn't find the answer. Thats why I'm here.

Answer (score 0):

if you want all records then try below code:

put this code in your DBAdapter class:

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAlldts() {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> todos = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> dtls = new HashMap<String, String>();

                dtls.put("nm", c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME))));
                dtls.put("age", c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AGE))));
                dtls.put("loc", c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATION))));
                todos.add(dtls);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        return todos;
    }

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getSomedts(int age) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> todos = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE+ " WHERE " + KEY_AGE + " = " + age+";

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> dtls = new HashMap<String, String>();

            dtls.put("nm", c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME))));
            dtls.put("age", c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AGE))));
            dtls.put("loc", c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATION))));
            todos.add(dtls);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return todos;
}
```

Now use this method in your activity class like below:

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Mondtls = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        Mondtls = db.getAlldts(); // db.getSomedts(25);
                for (int i = 0; i < Mondtls.size(); i++) {
                        String nm= Mondtls.get(i).get("nm");
            String age = Mondtls.get(i).get("age");
                        String loc = Mondtls.get(i).get("loc");
}
```

Now use this as per your needed.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for more of a specific entry in the database thats initiated by the user. Meaning, if the user input(by clicking etc) the value 'Kenneth', how do I pass the value 'Kenneth' from the MainActivity to the DBAdapter for searching/processing?